# Why is it that when I enter `{{ something }}`, it also gets displayed in `HTML`?

Tags: html, django

I tried entering this code in my `HTML`:

```html
<div>
  <input type="file" name="{{ form.forum_image }}" accept="image/*">
</div>
```

And this produces a site with the usual input file but after that is the text `" accept="image/*"></div>` What should I do with this so that it doesn't desplay the text? Image of the issue:
[image: picture].

Comment: Does `form.forum_image` contain quotes or html characters like `>`?

Comment: @JohnGordon No, I actually used Django forms and I am trying to apply styles using css for every field that I need to fill up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have closed that input tag off early somehow. If you right click on your HTML page in your browser, and choose 'view page source' , you can see how the line is actually being sent. The behavior you show is consistent with the line being something like

```
<div>
    <input type="file" name="image.gif">" accept="image/*">
</div>
```

If that's the case, you need to take a close look at your template and make sure you don't have a similar typo in there.

Comment: Thank you! I realized I need to put `name='author'` instead of `{{ form.author }}`. This is because `{{ form.author }}` automatically creates a `<select>` tag with its different options.